# Ruby: Insert a character into a string?

Tags: ruby

```
1
00:00:00000  -->00:00:00000
2
00:00:00730  -->00:00:04280
So when Sam originally sent me an email to do this course,  
3
00:00:04280  -->00:00:08400
he said Ben can you teach a 50 minute course on management.
```

I want to insert a `,` into`:00730`, so it becomes `:00,730`. How can I do that?

I'm thinking about

```
  path = 'lib/subtitle.txt'
  lines = IO.readlines(path).map do |line|
    *if contains 5 number, then insert a comma into it, like `gsub?`
  end
  File.open(path, 'w') do |file|
    file.puts lines
  end
```

But I'm not very familiar with Regex, is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using regular expression - capturing group and backreference ([`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org//core/String.html#method-i-gsub)):

```
"00:00:04280  -->00:00:08400".gsub(/(\d{2})(\d{3})/, '\1,\2')
# => "00:00:04,280  -->00:00:08,400"
```

capturing groups `(...)` can be referenced in replacement string with `\1`, `\2` (reference first, second captured group)